# VBA Excel: Add one second to a time

Tags: vba, time, excel

I'm working with a spreadsheet with two columns, in which one of the columns is a time. I have loaded the data into a dictionary using the time as a key. I want to look up the data corresponding to a particular time (easy), and then get the next data point so that I can compare their values. The data is recorded such that one piece of data is generated every second over a period of around two hours.

My question is, does VBA in Excel have a function which can automatically add one second to a time? Or do I need to manually write one?

Update: In addition to the answers below, I have also found the "DateAdd" function useful - I suspect it depends on the version of Excel being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should be able to use Time(hour, minute,second) function to add a second to the time.

so to add 1 second to a date with something like `Date(2012,1,16) + Time(0,0,1)` which should result in a value of "2012-01-16 12:00:01 AM"

Comment: I'm not sure how it was under previous versions of Excel VBA, but for at least Excel 2016 and up you would have to use `TimeSerial` instead of `Time`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use TimeValue("00:00:01") for adding in this example 1 second