# subtract 5 minutes from formated time and reformat answer with seconds

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VBA Excel: Add one second to a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875567/vba-excel-add-one-second-to-a-time)

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the time value formated as Custom 00"00".  I would like to subtract 5 minutes from this value and format the answer as hh:mm:ss using Excel VBA.  I have looked all over but have not found an answer.  I tried using various time functions but am not having much luck.  I am a new Excel VBA programmer.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the Cell holds a *real* date-time-value, you can go with something like this:

```
Cells(r, c).Value = DateAdd("n", -5, Cells(r, c).Value)
Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what custom format `00"00"` is supposed to do, but since you say you have "...spreadsheet with the time value..." I assume the underlying data is a Date/Time serial number.

If this is the case then

```
Dim cl as Range
Set cl = Range("YourCellAddress")
cl = cl - 5# / 1440# ' subtract 5 minutes
cl.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss" ' format
```