# Subtract seconds from date VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to subtract a number of seconds from a date. I have two columns one that lists the date in the format D/M/YY HH:MM AM/PM and the other lists a number seconds. I want to do:

```
07/28/15 12:08 AM - 60 = 07/28/15 12:07 AM
```

However if I subtract the two columns I get no value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Excel: Add one second to a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875567/vba-excel-add-one-second-to-a-time)

Comment: Tried to use Date - TIME(0;0;CELL) = , but this results also in the #VALUE! error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date in A1, # of seconds in A2

```
=A1-A2/86400
```

86400 being 24*60*60 to convert seconds into decimals

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. I still get the #Value! error in the cell

Comment: that means that your A1 may not be a date but a text ... try to change the format of this cell to **general** or **number** ... is it numeric then? (I trust your seconds - A2 - are numeric anyway)

Comment: It is a general format, if I change it to number it remains the same

Comment: aha !!! so you must bring A1 into a **date** format ... probably by `=DATEVALUE(text)` or `=DATE(y,m,d) + TIME(h,m,s)` ... in the 2nd case you may need to extract portions of your string using the `=MID(...)` function