# Compare unknown time stamps in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, date, timestamp

I have worksheets with a timestamp in the format of MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss

I want to be able to copy the row on which two timestamps from two different worksheets match, with a +1-second error margin. So if I have a timestamp with time 12:14:13, it will find a match with a timestamp of time 12:14:13 or 12:14:14. I don't want a ±1 second error margin, as it could match with wrong measurement readings. I have no way of knowing the timestamps beforehand.

As of now, I only have written code to match the timestamps exactly as text:

```
For i = 1 To counter 
'counter is the number of matches I want to find
    For Each cell In Range("C4:C" & LastRow)
'dateArray contains the timestamps to be matched
        If cell.Text = dateArray(i) Then
            Sheets("AlarmData").Range("BA" & cell.Row).Copy
            Sheets("Sensor_HWare_Alarms").Range("R" & i).PasteSpecial
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the end of your +1 second window I would add a second to the time using Time(hour, minute,second) as shown in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875661/5692872